# Query or deserialize json with dynamic keys using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have json that looks like this, the key "123" could be any number.

```
 {
   "key1": "",
   "key2": {
      "items": {
         "123": {
            "pageid": 123,
            "name": "data"
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

I want to deserialize or query the json with System.Text.Json so i can get the value of the key "name". How can I do that with System.Text.Json? I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public InnerObject key2 { get; set; }
}

public class InnerObject 
{
    public Dictionary<string, ObjectTheThird> items { get; set; }
        = new Dictionary<string, ObjectTheThird>();
}

public class ObjectTheThird
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and use the APIs on `Dictionary<,>` to look at the items. Or you just want the first:

```cs
var name = obj.key2.items.First().Value.name;
```

Comment: System.Text.Json won't populate the `items` dictionary unless the property has public setters and getters.  (In .NET 5 the setter can be private if the property is marked with `[JsonInclude]`).  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/AMq4ac vs https://dotnetfiddle.net/6PIuSG

Answer (score 3):

Since one of the json keys can vary (`"123"`), this can be represented by a `Dictionary<>`.  The following classes model your json.

```
public class ItemProps
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, ItemProps> items { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public Item key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize using `System.Text.Json` you would use:

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

To access `name`:

```
var name = data.key2.items["123"].name
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UaXtyk)

<sup>Note, I named the classes quickly... please consider giving the classes better names, more descriptive names.</sup>