# How to parse JSON dynamic KeyValuePair to C# model in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, json, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to parse JSON dynamic KeyValuePair response to C# model but getting an error. I am building an application using Blazor webassembly (latest version). I am quite sure that I am doing a silly mistake in JSON deserialization. Can you please correct me.

I am getting below JSON response from API:

```json
{
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "stores": {
            "": "Select Store",
            "21": "Indore store",
            "33": "test POS2",
            "34": "test POS4",
            "37": "test store 11",
            "36": "test store09",
            "59": "test store26"
        },
        "storeId": "21",
        "businessId": "1"
    }
}
```

And trying to parse response like this:

```cs
public async Task GetSetFilters()
{
    SetApiHeaders();
    var response = await Http.GetAsync("/pwa/v1/transaction-filters");
    TransactionFiltersModel content = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TransactionFiltersModel>();
}
```

My TransactionFiltersModel is:

```cs
public class TransactionFiltersModel
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public TransactionFiltersData data { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionFiltersData
{
    public string storeId { get; set; }
    public int businessId { get; set; }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> stores { get; set; }
}
```

Getting error:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]. Path: $.data.stores | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 43.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]. Path: $.data.stores | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 43.
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue (System.Type propertyType) <0x3070550 + 0x00032> in :0
> .....

Comment: Make `stores` be a `Dictionary<string, string>` not a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and it should work.  See [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182) or [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182).  (In fact I can't really see why you chose `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`, was there a reason for that?)

Comment: Ah, you are using [tag:system.text.json] internally.  But the answer is still the same, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521511/3744182) to [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207731/3744182) and also [Query or deserialize json with dynamic keys using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60089463/3744182).

Comment: does `Dictionary<string, string>` work for you or do you really need `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` for some reason?

Comment: Thanks @dbc, Dictionary<string, string> works. I see somewhere code snippet about List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>. Please post your answer so I can mark this question as answered.