# C# deserialize Json with ID nodes

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net, system.text.json

How can I deserialize Json into C# objects that have ID's for the node keys? For example:

```
{
  "people" : {
    "1": {
       "firstname": "jim",
       "lastname": "brown"
    },
    "2": {
       "firstname": "kathy",
       "lastname": "jones"  
    }
  }
}
```

Would serialize into this C# class

```
public class JsonRoot {
   public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible to do using either a custom generic converter or json attributes?

Comment: Replace `List<Person>` with `Dictionary<string, Person>`.

Comment: See: [Query or deserialize json with dynamic keys using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60089463/3744182), which looks to be a duplicate, agree?  or do you require the JSON object to be deserialized as a list?

Comment: You might be able to use `Dictionary<int, Person>` in .NET 5, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-next-for-system-text-json/#new-features: [Support non-string dictionary keys](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524).

Comment: Your Json string and classes don't match. `people` is an object/dictionary whose keys are numbers and whose values don't have an `Id` property. You'll have to deserialize this using *matching* classes and then map them to the classes you want

Comment: Dictionary<string, Person> works for what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this List will not give solution as there is no array in your json data.

Dictionary can be use and that is also two level. First dictionary contains only one key = person and its value is also dictionary and its key are "1" and "2" and value is person object.

```
class Program
{
    static string jsonData = @"{
                          ""people"" : {
                            ""1"": {
                               ""firstname"": ""jim"",
                               ""lastname"": ""brown""
                            },
                            ""2"": {
                               ""firstname"": ""kathy"",
                               ""lastname"": ""jones""  
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var datatextjson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>>(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`  -- question is about [tag:system.text.json] not [tag:json.net].

Comment: corrected and it is almost same.